# Can't find headphones, bluetooth seems working and finds other devices

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, headphones

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. I bought a pair of bluetooth headphones (Sony WS-CH500) but I can't pair them with my pc because I can't find the device or connect it with its MAC address. It doesn't seem to be a PC problem because I can connect my phone (a OnePlus 5T) and a speaker (Doss Soundbox) without problems.
I tried connecting the headphones to the smartphone and no problems occured.
I can't really understand where is the problem... somebody maybe can help me?

Here's the output of `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`:

```
[    0.028000] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    2.206837] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin (v1.1)
[    4.748174] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 34.0.1 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.772130] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.772142] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.772145] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.772146] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.772155] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.914233] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 185 week 49 2017
[    5.981887] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.981888] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.981891] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   30.026287] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   30.026297] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   30.026308] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   69.673237] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[   85.950240] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  121.135210] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  137.007251] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  152.870230] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  169.022205] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  184.882155] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  201.006216] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  500.039226] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  515.908232] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  532.043233] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  547.913218] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  564.048221] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  579.926361] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  596.048196] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  611.929509] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  628.060226] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  643.942226] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  660.067386] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  675.943146] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  692.079540] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  707.951218] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  724.076189] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  739.951280] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  756.083512] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  771.970208] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  788.095243] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  803.968232] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  820.093226] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  835.953255] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  852.074241] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  867.940212] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  884.063225] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  899.920221] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  916.052371] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  931.918563] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  948.040188] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  963.909411] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1001.030233] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1016.899230] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1033.020240] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1865.396152] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
[ 1865.396929] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[ 1865.396930] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[ 1865.396931] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[ 1865.396932] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[ 1865.396933] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[ 1865.396934] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[ 1865.398892] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
[ 1866.852269] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[ 1866.852937] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1424562 usecs
[ 1866.853216] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[ 1866.870072] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 16615 usecs
[ 1866.870331] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-12-16.ddc
[ 1866.873120] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[ 1909.001342] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 34.0.1
[ 1912.875329] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1929.000196] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1944.873994] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1961.001042] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1976.872964] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1992.996004] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2008.872326] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2024.998072] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2040.868045] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2056.991984] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2072.868961] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2088.988970] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2104.862094] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2120.988214] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2136.871000] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2152.996236] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2168.866336] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2184.987984] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2200.872026] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2216.997057] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2232.859028] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2248.991020] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2264.861318] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2280.992994] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2296.866977] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2312.994991] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2328.879229] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2344.991999] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2358.816975] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2374.946991] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2391.071978] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2406.943934] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2423.074002] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2438.942961] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2455.077361] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2470.840433] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2489.843934] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3012.892000] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3029.019032] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3044.889318] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3061.017996] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3076.884328] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3093.016005] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3108.884944] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3125.020018] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3140.883953] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3157.021125] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3172.886223] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3189.013037] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3204.889010] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3221.026026] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3236.913026] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3253.049199] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3268.932944] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3285.071271] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3300.954319] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3317.075963] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3332.959963] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3349.084194] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3364.950993] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3381.080200] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3396.945032] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3413.084027] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3428.950324] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3445.075999] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3460.943998] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3477.075321] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3492.949990] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3509.084202] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3524.961000] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3541.084001] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3556.958275] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3573.094213] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3588.961005] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3605.096054] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3629.914992] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3645.649016] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3661.776995] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3678.009999] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3693.881311] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3710.006000] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3725.880994] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3742.005005] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3757.878334] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3774.001160] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3789.869959] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3806.000186] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3821.882011] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3833.908191] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3850.035001] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3865.914010] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3882.050958] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3897.924334] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3914.061124] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3929.937170] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3946.072993] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3961.937987] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3978.075170] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 3993.943997] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4010.077980] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4025.953983] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4042.081992] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4057.957955] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4074.097994] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4089.964012] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4106.096185] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4121.972946] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4138.099993] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4153.982997] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4170.100014] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4185.977018] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4202.106966] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4217.975995] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4234.109977] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4249.990312] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4266.109148] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4281.999032] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4298.112155] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4313.992000] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4330.113008] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4345.988964] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4362.128001] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4377.997029] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4394.128003] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4409.997008] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4426.123996] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4442.002000] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 4458.137038] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

and `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:1e.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluetooth is a stinking pile of... well, it's a [convoluted, flaky mess](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13125537) that does somehow manage to work stably a reasonable amount of the time.

The fact is, pretty much every bluetooth implementation is buggy in different ways. So even if your PC works with some devices the problem could well be on the PC side in this case.

Or the problem could be as simple as you turning the bluetooth headphones on but not putting them in discoverable mode (check the headphones' manual).

I have found https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser to be helpful as it has lots of different approaches

Comment: My headphones are always discoverable, in facts my phone founds it with the first try... anyway I tried using bluetoothctl and setting "discoverable on" and "scan on" yesterday. Nothing changed... 

Comment: Have you tried `hcitool scan`? If you know the MAC address you can try `sudo hidd --connect <BT_Address>` or `rfcomm connect hci0 <BT address>`, as mentioned on the BluetoothUser page. Any luck?

Comment: Hey, with `sudo rfcomm connect hci0 <BT address>` works (without `sudo` it gave me permission denied)! Now I'm connected, but I can't use it as audio manager doesn't see it... any idea? 

EDIT: I think I solved using blueman and connecting it as audio source. Now I have to understand if I'll have to do this thing everytime.

Comment: It seems that now my headphones are saved in the gnome bluetooth menu. I can connect and disconnect from there. Thank you!