# Bluetooth can't find headphones on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, headphones, rfkill, detect

Similarly to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104326/cant-find-headphones-bluetooth-seems-working-and-finds-other-devices) question I can't pair my new headphones (Marshall Major III) to my laptop because I can't find the device. I can connect the headphones to my phone (XperiaL1) and my laptop can detect my phone. I read other answers and I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090774/bluetooth-cant-find-headphones) solution:

```
rfkill block bluetooth
sudo service bluetooth stop
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Nothing changed. The strangest thing is that yesterday my headphones were both detected and connected to my laptop!

The output of `service bluetooth status`

```
<pre><font color="#8AE234"><b>●</b></font> bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: <font color="#8AE234"><b>active (running)</b></font> since Fri 2020-06-05 14:25:31 EEST; 18min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 911 (bluetoothd)
   Status: &quot;Running&quot;
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─911 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Ιουν 05 14:25:31 piyi-Inspiron-5558 bluetoothd[911]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
Ιουν 05 14:25:31 piyi-Inspiron-5558 bluetoothd[911]: Starting SDP server
Ιουν 05 14:25:31 piyi-Inspiron-5558 bluetoothd[911]: Bluetooth management interf
Ιουν 05 14:25:31 piyi-Inspiron-5558 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Ιουν 05 14:25:31 piyi-Inspiron-5558 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Ιουν 05 14:26:20 piyi-Inspiron-5558 bluetoothd[911]: Endpoint registered: sender
Ιουν 05 14:26:20 piyi-Inspiron-5558 bluetoothd[911]: Endpoint registered: sender
<span style="background-color:#FFFFFF"><font color="#300A24">lines 1-17/17 (END)</font></span>
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Marshall Major III needs to be put in *discoverable* mode before Bluetooth can detect it.

After you turn it on, keep pressing the (one) button until you hear a second sound, consisting of two tones. After a few moments, the headphone appears in the list.

I suppose this works for many other Bluetooth devices.